# Get value from matplotlib to tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am opening matplotlib Windows from a tkinter gui. It would be usefull to get the Limits back to tkinter to handle the next window open Event with the predefined Limits. To do this I defined a new button in the menue of the matplotlib window, that should can write the limits to console, but it cannot write into the TK window.

I tried the following, but it is crashing for unknown reasons:

```
from Tkinter import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

master = Tk()

e = Entry(master)
e.pack()

e.focus_set()

def callback():
    def a():
        print(ax.get_xlim())
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(0, ax.get_xlim()[0])

    fig,ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
    plt.plot([1, 2, 3])
    fig.canvas.manager.toolbar.addAction("Write limit\nback to gui",a)
    plt.show()

b = Button(master, text="Open matplotlib", width=15, command=callback)
b.pack()

mainloop()
```

A working alternative I tried is to use callbacks, but it would be a lot nice to have the Information displayed instantaniously.

```
from Tkinter import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

master = Tk()
global A
A=[]
e = Entry(master)
e.pack()

e.focus_set()

def func(Hubbel):
    if len(A):
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(0, A[0])

master.bind("<FocusIn>", func)

def callback():
    def a():
        print(ax.get_xlim())
        print(A)
        if len(A)==0:
            A.append(ax.get_xlim())
        else:
            A[0]=ax.get_xlim()

    fig,ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
    plt.plot([1, 2, 3])
    fig.canvas.manager.toolbar.addAction("Write limit\nback to gui",a)
    plt.show()

b = Button(master, text="Open matplotlib", width=15, command=callback)
b.pack()

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

`plt.show()` blocks the execution of the event loop of your tkinter application. You will have the values correclty inserted once you close the plotting window created by `plt.show()` because at that point the tk events are being handled.

A way to avoid this is to call `fig.show()` instead. This will only work because you already have the tk event loop running.

Comment: If I use fig.show() instead, the behaviour is exaclty the same on my machine